# Apache Ignite's example(Ignite JDBC Driver) cann't be connected because of no suitable driver found for url(jdbc:mysql://***)

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I try to load cache from the given data source,but failed.

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platform75
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:538)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:497)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:228)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5753)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5802)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6473)
        at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2V2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:2037)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:556)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6564)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:550)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:479)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1375)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:643)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:535)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:679)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:403)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:417)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:390)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.globalLoadCacheAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:3790)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.globalLoadCache(GridCacheAdapter.java:3729)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.loadCache(IgniteCacheProxy.java:390)
        at com.primeton.ignitedb.example.CacheSpringStore.loadCache(CacheSpringStore.java:113)
        at com.primeton.ignitedb.example.CacheSpringStore.main(CacheSpringStore.java:91)
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platform75
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:692)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:724)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:749)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:764)
        at com.primeton.ignitedb.example.CacheSpringPersonStore.loadCache(CacheSpringPersonStore.java:130)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore.loadCache(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:369)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:512)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platform75
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:192)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:353)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:385)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:227)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        ... 34 more
```

The code is below:

```
// Configure Spring session listener.
                cacheCfg.setCacheStoreSessionListenerFactories(new Factory<CacheStoreSessionListener>() {
                    @Override public CacheStoreSessionListener create() {
                        CacheSpringStoreSessionListener lsnr = new CacheSpringStoreSessionListener();

                        lsnr.setDataSource(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platform75",
        "root", "root"));
                        return lsnr;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing: your title mentions the _Ignite_ JDBC driver, you connect with a _MySQL_ JDBC url, using a _H2_ datasource. You need to show more code, especially the datasource configuration. And if you are following some example, at minimum provide a link to that example.

Comment: Thank you for your passionate answer,the connection is :Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver");Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:ignite:cfg://cache=%s@%s", "cacheName", CacheSpringStore.SPRING_CFG_PATH));

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to load data from MySQL to Ignite, you need to have MySQL driver on classpath. Just put the driver JAR into `IGNITE_HOME/libs` folder prior to starting the nodes, and rerun data loading.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see on the forums, you solve a lot of questions about Apache Ignite for others, consider using this cached frameworks in our products is currently being explored. Want to give us your advice.

Comment: In addition, there is also a question: If we use Apache Ignite to connect to  Mysql database, is the memory support LEFT JOIN OR INNER JOIN? Another question is that the Apache Ignite how to keep consistent when refreshing the databasein real time?

Comment: All types of joins are supported. To make data consistent you should update data through Ignite with write-through. If you update DB directly, you will have to manually reload corresponding entries.

Comment: When using the web-console generated docker image - how do I make sure the MySQL JDBC driver will be put in the `IGNITE_HOME/libs` folder? I've tried putting it in the `jdbc_drivers` folder but that didn't help.